Horror Movie with a Father Trying To Save His Son
I do not remember much. But just a few details:
A boy is perhaps cursed or something, his father is on a trail to free his boy from it. I remember a scene where the boy's father is walking/running a sharp thing falls and beheads a guy passing by but not the father. Probably the father was going to or coming from a church when the sharp thing fell off and cut a guy's head.
Probably late 90's or early 2000's. It's an English horror movie.

Please try to add any detail that may help identification. Are there any other plot details or any relevant descriptions you might remember?

Probably the father was going to or coming from a church when the sharp thing fell off and cut a guy's head. That's all I remember.

Possibly the Omen remake from 2006, where an American diplomat (Liev Schreiber) suspects that his son is the Devil. He's helped by a photographer called Jennings (David Thewlis), who, just like in the original film, is beheaded (in this version by a large sign falling on him). Here's the trailer:




I probably think this is the one.
